# Counting points on elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

Consider the Legendre family of elliptic curves
$$E_a: y^2=x(x-1)(x-a).$$
Let $p$ be an odd prime.

> **QUESTION.** Is the following true? If $p\equiv 3\pmod4$ then number of solutions to $E_2$
> over the finite field $\mathbf{F}_p$ is
> $$\#(E_2/\mathbf{F}_p)\equiv 0 \pmod p.$$

Comment: Yes, because substituting x+1 for x identifies E_2 with the curve y^2 = x^3 - x for which this result is well known.  (Indeed the count is exactly p.  Not p+1, because as stated the question excludes the point at infinity.)

Comment: That curve has complex multiplication by $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ so, $a_p=0$ for all primes $p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. That means that the number of affine points is $p$ and the group order is $p+1$.

Comment: Thanks to both Noam D. Elkies and Chris Wuthrich.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Corresponding sums of Legendre symbols are know as [Jacobsthal sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_sum)  $$J(u)=\sum_{x\mod p}\left(\frac {x^3+ux}p\right).$$
They are equal to $0$ for prime  $p\equiv 3\pmod4$. If $p\equiv 1\pmod4
$, $\left(\frac ap\right)=1$ and $\left(\frac bp\right)=-1$, then $J(a)$, $J(b)$ are even and
$$\left(\frac {J(a)}2\right)^2+\left(\frac {J(b)}2\right)^2=p.$$

The original Jacobsthal's article is available [here.](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/download/pdf/PPN243919689_0132/LOG_0017.pdf)

Comment: I think that this (or something easily equivalent) was already known to Gauss as part of hiw work on quartic (a.k.a. "biquadratic") reciprocity.